# PrimeFaces: formatting <div style="float:right;"> causes command button not to work?

Tags: html, css, primefaces, css-float

1.) When I have this:

```
            <div style="float:right; width:68%;">
                <ui:insert name="main_box"/>
            </div>
```

the content of the main_box is delivered, but the user is NOT able to click on neither the drop down box, nor the command button inside it. Debugging in the browser also does not show ANY request being sent.

2.) However, when I remove the float:right formatting like this:

```
            <div style="width:68%;">
                <ui:insert name="main_box"/>
            </div>
```

then the user is able to click both on the drop down box and on the command button. It seems that the float formatting somehow disables the controls.

Here is a complete minimal example:

1.) The facelet new_customer.xhtml:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/includes/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="main_box">
            <h:form id="formId">
                <p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />
                <p:panel header="Create a new customer" />
                <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" border="1" cellpadding="10"
                    cellspacing="1">
                    <p:outputLabel for="kundeTypId" value="Kunde Typ:" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="kundeTypId"
                        value="#{newCustomerBean.custmerType}" style="width:150px">
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="@this formId"
                            process="@this formId" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Kunde auswählen" itemValue=""
                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{newCustomerBean.custmerTypes}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel id="vornameLabelId" for="vornameId"
                        value="#{newCustomerBean.custmerType eq 'TYP_NATPERS' ? 'Vorname' : 'Name'}"
                        rendered="#{newCustomerBean.custmerType eq 'TYP_NATPERS' or newCustomerBean.custmerType eq 'TYP_FIRMA'}" />
                    <p:inputText id="vornameId" value="#{newCustomerBean.vorname}"
                        rendered="#{newCustomerBean.custmerType eq 'TYP_NATPERS' or newCustomerBean.custmerType eq 'TYP_FIRMA'}"
                        maxlength="25" size="20" />

                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Create Customer"
                    icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{newCustomerBean.saveNewCustomer}" />
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

2.) The Template template.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Alex-Mi example </title> 
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/styles.css"  />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="common.js" />
         <div id="container">
                 <ui:insert name="menu" />
                 <div id="content" class ="content">
                     <div id = "dropzone" style="float:left; width:32%;">
                        <img id="preview" src='../images/library_small.jpg' alt='library'  style="width: 280px; height: 160 px;"/>
                        <select name="top5" id="flist" size="5"></select>
                        <output id="list"></output>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right; width:68%;">
                        <ui:insert name="main_box"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer">
                        <p id="usersOnline"></p>
                        <p>Copyright @2017 Alex-Mi</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

3.) My CSS file:

```
/** footer **/

#footer {
    padding-top: 2em;
    position: relative;
}

#footer p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
```

3.) The Backing Bean NewCustomerBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NewCustomerBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public enum KundeTyp {

        TYP_NATPERS("Nat. Person"), TYP_FIRMA("Firma");

        private String value;

        private KundeTyp(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    private KundeTyp custmerType;
    private Map<String, KundeTyp> custmerTypes;

    private String vorname;

    private String kundeTyp = Integer.MIN_VALUE + "";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        custmerTypes = new HashMap<String, KundeTyp>();
        custmerTypes.put(KundeTyp.TYP_NATPERS.value, KundeTyp.TYP_NATPERS);
        custmerTypes.put(KundeTyp.TYP_FIRMA.value, KundeTyp.TYP_FIRMA);
    }

    public KundeTyp getCustmerType() {
        return custmerType;
    }

    public void setCustmerType(KundeTyp custmerType) {
        this.custmerType = custmerType;
    }

    public Map<String, KundeTyp> getCustmerTypes() {
        return custmerTypes;
    }

    public void setCustmerTypes(Map<String, KundeTyp> custmerTypes) {
        this.custmerTypes = custmerTypes;
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public String getKundeTyp() {
        return kundeTyp;
    }

    public void setKundeTyp(String kundenTyp) {
        this.kundeTyp = kundenTyp;
    }

    public String saveNewCustomer() {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "OK",
                    "New customer saved " ));

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you make this into a [mcve]? And post version info please

Comment: @Kukeltje 10x, Let me some time to do so. Which version info do you mean? Do you mean PrimeFaces, HTML, etc. versions, or the verison of my own source code?

Comment: Minimal, Complete and verifyable example provided

Comment: So it works if you don't use a template?

Comment: @Kukeltje, the problem is not in the template. Guess where (and why...) . The "soltion" is to add one row in the .css file to the #footer class as follows:                                                                                                                          clear: both;

Comment: If the problem is not in the template then next time **don't** post it in the Q. WE can never know/see/guess/... what might be in there that could cause this behaviour. Therefore always, always create a [mcve]... see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info... So we can still not guess why the solution work. And "don't work" is to vague. What does happen? Is the click not resulting in http traffic? Use a browser developer tool to check if something else is 'stacked' on top of them...

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around to the problem above, but it still does not explain what the problem is and where it is. Here is the work-around:

```
clear: both;
```

to the css file:

```
#footer {
    padding-top: 2em;
    position: relative;
    clear: both; 
}
```

I can explain what the row is supoosed to do: It just clears the float: formatting for the div with id footer. But I cannot explain why this influences the behaviour of both my PrimeFaces drop down list and the command button. Can somebody help me?